# Trouble with MJPG stream from IP camera in C#

Tags: c#, camera, webserver

I'm trying to connect to an Amcrest IP camera via C# winforms.  Here is what I am trying and the instructions from the Amcrest API manual.  I don't get any errors running this code but my picturebox never updates.  This is my first dive into working with an IP camera or doing any sort of server requests.  Can anyone steer me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

```
    private void Connect()
    {
        // Omitting the username and password does not help either.
        MJPEGStream stream = new MJPEGStream("http://192.168.1.108/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=0&username=admin&password=pwd11");
        stream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        stream.Start();
    }

    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
```

[image: API document image]

There is this section in the manual regarding authentication.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Aforge.Video.dll? Have you tried adding a handler to the [VideoSourceError](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/e0862f1c-222b-7a2a-de3b-baf9b6e0013b.htm) event?

Comment: (edited)I just did now.  I get the error "The remote server returned an error: (401) unauthorized".  I'm taking this to mean my username and password are not correct but I know they are.  I can login via webpage just fine.

Comment: Then try to set the `Login` and `Password` properties instead of providing them in the url.

Comment: I will look up how to do that, but if you know off hand how to do it, it would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: `stream.Login = "username"` and stream.Password = "password"` before you call `stream. Start()`, I suppose.. Please have a look at the docs linked in my first comment, you didn't even confirmed if you are using the aforge library.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am using the aforge library.  I tried setting the login and password but got the same 401 result.  I found a section in the api manual regarding authentication (which I added to my original post just now) and it says to encode with base64.  I tried that but still got the same 401 result.

Comment: Also tried `stream.ForceBasicAuthentication = true`?

Comment: Just tried it now.  No luck.

Comment: Found in a forum post here (https://amcrest.com/forum/ip-cameras-f18/authentication-examples--t7128.html) that apparently basic authentication is no longer supported in later firmware versions.  I will look up how to do digest authentication but again, if you have a quick solution, it would be a big help.  Thank you so much so far!

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1):

```
working.....

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stream = new MJPEGStream("http://192.168.1.108/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=0&subtype=1");
            stream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        }
        private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }
        private void startbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stream.Login = "admin";
            stream.Password = "passwordx";
            stream.Start();
        }
        private void stopbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stream.Stop();
        }
```